# C++ memory management for a vector with variable length items

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, struct

Take a variable length struct (if this were a *real* program, an int array would be better):

```
#include <vector>
struct list_of_numbers(){
  int length;
  int *numbers; //length elements.
};
typedef std::vector<list_of_numbers> list_nums; //just a writing shortcut

(...)
```

And build a vector out of it:

```
list_nums lst(10); //make 10 lists.
lst[0].length = 7; //make the first one 7 long.
lst[0].X = new int[7]; //allocate it with new[]

(...)
```

The above works for g++ in ubuntu. The new() calls are needed to avoid segfaults. Can the lst vector be deleted all at once when it is no longer needed, or will the new calls cause a memory leak? It would be tedious to manually delete() all of the parts called with new().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you would want to put cleanup code in the destructor of the object (`~list_of_numbers()`) and memory creating code in the constructor (`list_of_numbers()`). That way these things are handled for you when the destructor is called (or when the object is created).

Comment: You would also have to implement the copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: @DeadMG:  If it's not copyable, you aren't going to be putting instances of it in a vector :-).

Comment: I like this answer. It actually gets to the point. And you read what I said:
"(if this were a real program, an int array would be better)". 
This was actually the expected answer.

Comment: @James McNellis: Depends on if you're using C++0x.

Comment: @DeadMG:  Ok, so if you have a move-aware containers library implementation, you need either to implement the copy constructor and copy assignment operator OR the move constructor and the move assignment operator.  You still have to do _something_ because the implicitly declared special member functions aren't going to do what we need them to do.

Answer (score 4):

The typical ways to do this in C++ would be to define constructors and destructors and assignment operators for the `list_of_numbers` struct that take care of the memory management, or (much better) use a `std::vector<int>` for the `numbers` field and get rid of the `length` field.

But if you do that, you may as well get rid of the struct entirely, and just do this:

```
#include <vector>
typedef std::vector<int> list_ints;
typedef std::vector<int_ints> list_lists;

(...)

list_lists lst(10); // make 10 lists.
lst[0].resize(7);   // set length of the zeroth list to 7
```

Comment: small code typo typedef std::vector<int_ints> list_lists; -> typedef std::vector<list_ints> list_lists;

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a vector of vector of int? That's it's job. You should not be calling new outside of a dedicated class.